# Spring Test Authentication

Tags: model-view-controller, mockito

Tell me who can. The unit test fails for some reason, a response 401 arrives with the message Error message = Unauthorized. This is despite the fact that my /hello page is open in the filter for everyone

```
@WebMvcTest(HelloController.class)
class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testHelloPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("hello"));
    }
}
```